# is the audio source for .yuv test video sequences available?

Tags: audio, video-processing, yuv, encoder, libyuv

i need the audio file for the yuv test video sequences like foreman.yuv, akiyo.yuv 
,etc. none of the yuv sequences online have the audio file.
any other yuv sequences with the audio file suitable for encoder analysis also works.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no audio available for the sequences you mention.

But have a look at https://media.xiph.org/video/derf/, at the bottom of the page you have full sequences with flac audio.